# SWRevealController not calling UITableViewDelegate methods easily

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-frameworks

I'm using the `SWRevealController` for displaying a slideout menu and the table view `datasource` is working fine, however the `delegate` methods that requires user interaction are not being called easily. 
For example the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` basically doesn't work and `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` works only if the user does a long press.
Why is it happening? Does it have any solution?

Comment: do you have any gesture recognizers on the tableview that may conflict with the tap on the cell?

Comment: Not on the tableview, but I have it on the SWRevealController for openning the menu. Is it a unconsidered case?

Comment: yes it may be. Try to set `cancelTouchesInView = NO` on the gesture recognizer and see if it helps